# inconsistency in outcome status when execute test method between TFS2017 & TFS2015

Tags: tfs

I created a test method that uses "Assert.Inconclusive(skipMessage)" function. On TFS2015, the executing outcome is 'done', but on TFS2017 the executing outcome is 'not executed'.

Could you please help me to make the outcome is 'done' when using "Assert.Inconclusive(skipMessage)" on TFS2017?

[image]

Comment: What version of the nunit adapter are you using? Is it the same on each platform?

Comment: do you mean this reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll?
They are difference in version between the one for TFS2017 (AssemblyFileVersion("15.0.26228.0")) & TFS2015 (AssemblyFileVersion("12.0.21005.1")).

Comment: That assembly is for microsoft's test framework, not NUnit. If you are using NUnit, you should be referencing some version of the nunit3-vs-adapter or possibly the nunit-vs-adapter. If you are not using nunit, kindly remove the nunit tag to avoid wasting time.

Comment: I don't get it. I'm using Microsoft's test framework. I don't think there is a nunit adapter in here. Could you please explain it more details?

Comment: @ThànhLongNguyễn I tested your issue in TFS 2015 and  2017. The result I got was both in the 2 versions, it shows 'Not executed'. It doesn't shows done. Please check again your test results in TFS 2015.

Comment: Thank bro, I checked on TFS 2015 and got the same result with TFS 2017. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: You tagged your question nunit, leading me to ask you about the nunit adapter. Please remove the tag. Many of us get notices for certain tags and try to help folks having problem with a particular piece of software, so proper tagging helps you get the right people to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both TFS 2015 and TFS 2017, the Skipper test methods are both shown like 'not executed' not 'Done'.

This settings in TFS can't be changed. But if you want to change/edit the outcome of a specify test result, you could use [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#update-test-results-for-a-test-run) to achieve this.

```
HTTP Method: PATCH
URL: http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamProject/_apis/test/runs/testrunId/results?api-version=3.0-preview

Json object: 
{
    "id": 100000,    --this is test result id
    "outcome": "None"  
}
```

You could change the outcome from `NotExecuted` to `None, Passed, Failed, Inconclusive, Timeout, Aborted, Blocked, Warning, Error, NotApplicable, Paused or InProgress`.